# Why are object attributes used in a function said to be unbound variables?

Tags: python, cpython

I'm using the `inspect` module to learn more about function namespaces:

```
import inspect

def foo():
    inspect.__cache__.update({'dummy': 0}) # Could be any class/attribute here

print(inspect.getclosurevars(foo))
```

Reformatted output:

```
ClosureVars(
    nonlocals={}, 
    globals={'inspect': <module 'inspect' from ='C:\\Users\\guido\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\inspect.py'>}, 
    builtins={}, 
    unbound={'__cache__', 'update'}
)
```

Why are attributes of objects used in a function (i.e. `__cache__` and `update` in this particular case) said to be unbound variables?

---

Upon a [closer look](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4b8cdfcb22fbeaab9d954cb693a7fb3362a382b6/Lib/inspect.py#L1432), `inspect.getclosurevars` determines unbound variables from the bytecodes. More specifically, it returns variables in `foo.__code__.co_names` that is in `foo.__globals__`.

So the real questions are perhaps:

- Do object attributes belong in `foo.__code__.co_names` as per the current definition? This is a difficult question on itself because it seems like the definition is [yet to be determined](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/2743)
- Is it correct for the `inspect` module to determine `unbound` variables like it is currently doing? Here correct refers to whether the returns conform to the definition of `unbound` variables.

Comment: `getclosurevars` is just buggy. That's not the only failing case.

Comment: There's a [related issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue26577) on the tracker, with no response, posted in 2016.